# MySQL: Conditions for JOIN ON SELECT UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, join

The idea for my MySQL query is to create a union of tables of a certain type, such as vendors (e.g. retailer, wholesaler, etc).  Once I have the vendors, I want to select the name and address of the vendor assigned to the order.

I have a JOIN:

```
SELECT o.*, v.*
FROM order o
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 'retailer' AS type, r.id AS type_id, r.name, r.address FROM retailer AS r
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'wholesaler' AS type, w.id AS type_id, w.name, w.address FROM wholesaler AS w
) AS v ON CONVERT(v.type AS utf8) = o.vendor_type AND CONVERT(v.type_id AS utf8) = o.vendor_type_id
```

**Question 1: Do you think this is the best way to do this?**

> a) A vendor table would not be any better unless there is a name and
>   address field to select in the vendor table; this seems redundant
>   since the name and address are already in the vendor-specific table
>   (e.g. retailer table)
>
> b) Maybe a LEFT JOIN on each vendor-specific table would be best,
>   though the NULL values everywhere would get kind of ugly. 
>   Performance-wise, yes, this is probably the best option.  The UNION
>   seems a bit bulky.  Thoughts?

**Question 2**: I am having to use CONVERT() on my JOIN conditions where the fields are coming from the UNION.  The UNION fields are COERCIBLE and all other fields are latin_swedish.  Do you think using CONVERT() in the conditions will slow down my JOIN?

Comment: Why are they split into different tables?

Comment: Thanks for asking.  They are split because their purposes are very different; their associated tables aren't the same either.  The above table names are just theoretical.

Comment: Using a `convert()` in the `join` will probably slow it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is probably more efficient, because it can make use of indexes on `retailer(id)` and `wholesaler(id)`:

```
SELECT o.*, coalesce(r.name, w.name) as name, coalesce(r.address, w.address) as address
FROM order o left outer join
     retailer r
     on o.type_id = r.id and o.type = 'retailer' left outer join
     wholesaler w
     on o.type_id = w.id and o.type = 'wholesaler';
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm thinking, too.  This may be difficult to write in Zend_Db_Select.  I imagine I would add the COALESCE to the Zend_Db_Select::from().

Comment: Yes. I just tested this and it's working like a charm in Zend.  I'm now certain, as you were, that the left joins with coalesce are superior in performance.  Muchas gracias.  Soy feliz que tu me podria ayudar hoy.